# Problema ao salvar dados na base de dados

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Criei uma aplicação simples, porém ao clicar no botão de ação responsável por salvar o dado, o programa para de funcionar.

Segue imagem:

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Ação do botão Save:**-

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Chemical newChemical = new Chemical();

            newChemical.ChemicalName = nameField.Text;
            newChemical.ChemicalFormula = formulaField.Text;
            newChemical.MW = Decimal.Parse(MWField.Text);
            newChemical.VFId = Int32.Parse(VFIDField.Text);

            ctrl.Create(newChemical);
        }
```

**Código do Controle (ctrl):**

```
public class ChemicalCtrl
{

    public ChemicalCtrl()
    { }

    public void Create(Chemical ch)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        try
        {
            using (var repo = new Repository<Chemical>())
            {
                repo.Create(ch);
            }
        }
        catch(CustomExceptionsCtrl err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err);
        }

    }
}
```

**DETALHE: Eu ja testei o método 'Create()' em uma aplicação console, está funcionando perfeitamente.**

Comment: O que a solução de problema apresenta como erro? Se não me falha a memória ele consegue algumas  informações relevantes nesse caso.

Comment: Olá @GabrielColetta consegui resolver o problema, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, o problema era bem simples, achei estranho, **porém resolvido**...

O seguinte erro era porque eu tenho uma outra classe no sistema na qual possuia uma propriedade que não foi espelhada no banco de dados (não utilizei o Migrations para atualizá-la). Para corrigir isso, tive que comentar as duas propriedades na classe para poder rodar o software.

O que achei estranho era o seguinte: Não dava erro de compilação e o console não me mostrava falha nenhuma de execução.

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente o erro está acontecendo devido a uma conversão que está retornando uma exceção. Mais precisamente nessas linhas:

```
newChemical.MW = Decimal.Parse(MWField.Text);
newChemical.VFId = Int32.Parse(VFIDField.Text);
```

Adicionei um `try catch` no seu código (para identificar possíveis erros) e alterei o método `Parse` para `TryParse`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Chemical newChemical = new Chemical();

        newChemical.ChemicalName = nameField.Text;
        newChemical.ChemicalFormula = formulaField.Text;

        if (Decimal.TryParse(MWField.Text, out var mw))
        {
            newChemical.MW = mw;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Valores inválidos para MW.");
            MWField.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (Int32.TryParse(VFIDField.Text, out var vfid))
        {
            newChemical.VFID = vfid;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Valores inválidos para VFID.");
            VFIDField.Focus();
            return;
        }

        ChemicalCtrl ctrl = new ChemicalCtrl();
        ctrl.Create(newChemical);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Erro ao criar: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Além disso, no seu código não existe a criação do objeto `ChemicalCtrl`, o que pode estar gerando erro também. Adicionei a criação do mesmo, assim como a chamada para o método `Create()`:

```
ChemicalCtrl ctrl = new ChemicalCtrl();
ctrl.Create(newChemical);
```